# Websphere Appserver v9 test Data Source connection fails

Tags: java, datasource, sybase, websphere-9

I have configured a sybase datasource on websphere applicaiton server 9 installed on **Linux**,and trying to test it. But it fails with below exception

```
>DSConfigurati W DSRA8201W: DataSource Configuration: DSRA8040I: Failed to 
>connect to the DataSource jdbc/gbs. Encountered java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: 
>Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0TS: Truncation error trying to 
>send GBSÃÂ«ÃÂ¼ÃÂÃÂ¢ÃÂ³ÃÂ½ÃÂÃÂ²ÃÂ®ÃÂªÃÂ°ÃÂ»L. DSRA0010E: SQL State = JZ006,
```

during data source configuration ,I have added couple of custom properties for data source and they are

```
> networkProtocol : Tds  
> connectionProperties: 
>SELECT_OPENS_CURSOR=true;applicationName=GBS«¼Æ¢ó½Ç²îª°»L
```

I just searched the Sybase error code JZ0TS  in here  infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/…, but that really dint help me .

What I observed is the custom property value GBS«¼Æ¢ó½Ç²îª°»L  is getting changed to GBSÃÂ«ÃÂ¼ÃÂÃÂ¢ÃÂ³ÃÂ½ÃÂÃÂ²ÃÂ®ÃÂªÃÂ°ÃÂ»L  , during connectivity testing. How to avoid this.

Can any one help me on this.

The Environment I have used for this are ...

- Websphere Application Server 9.0.0.10
- Sybase Jconnect 3 jar  and the
- OS where the WAS 9.x installed is Linux.

I have tried the same test datasource connection verificaiton on Websphere application server version 9 installed on **Windows 10** , it worked fine , without any issues.